# Extract each data from this json String

Tags: java, json, gson

```
{
  "data": "{\"demand_amt\":8.058720825E7,\"coll_amt\":7.576150165E7,\"collefficiency\":94.01182060429548}",
  "err_flag": 0,
  "disp_msg": "service executed succeessfully"
}
```

This is a json String.And I have to extract each data from this json String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, Object> jsonMap = gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);
String innerJsonString= (String)jsonMap.get("data");
Map<String, Object> jsonDataMap = gson.fromJson(innerJsonString, type);
```

> **demand_amt**
>
> jsonDataMap.get("demand_amt");
>
> **coll_amt**
>
> jsonDataMap.get("coll_amt");
>
> **collefficiency**
>
> jsonDataMap.get("collefficiency");
>
> **err_flag**
>
> jsonMap.get("err_flag");
>
> **disp_msg**
>
> jsonMap.get("disp_msg");

Note: You may have to cast Objects as per your requirement.

Comment: It doesn't work...

Comment: Any exception is thrown?

Comment: @Programmer I guess you're missing the fact that the given JSON has another JSON-encoded value in the `data` property as a `String` -- it requires sub-parsing, thus it cannot be cast to a `Map` directory. I also guess that the OP is confused with `.get(data)` and `.get("data")` (this also fits "it doesn't work").

Comment: I tried this code:- JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(rs);
    String newJSON = jsonObject.getString("data"); I got                {"demand_amt":8.058720825E7,"coll_amt":7.576150165E7,"collefficiency":94.01182060429548}   . And Now I have to extract each of the data from this string.

Comment: Map<String, Object> jsonDataMap = jsonMap.get(data); The 'data' shows error.

Comment: @Ajmal The code you provided is Gson-unrelated.

Comment: yeah...It's works fine...Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/google/gson to extract and parse JSON in Java

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson):

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement json = parser.parse(jsonString);
JsonElement data = json.get("data");
//etc
```